# How Can I get this output using fuzzywuzzy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, fuzzywuzzy

If I have two dataframes (John,Alex,harry) and (ryan, kane, king). How can I use fuzzywuzzy in python to get the following output.

```
                              fuzz.Ratio  
John        ryan               25          
John        kane               54
John        king               44
alex        ryan               23
alex        kane               14
alex        king               55
harry       ryan               47
harry       kane               47
harry       king               50
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ratios are wrong. What you are looking for is cartesian product of the corresponding columns of both the dataframes.

Sample code:

```
import itertools

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['John','Alex','harry']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['ryan','kane','king']})

for w1, w2 in  itertools.product(
    df1['name'].apply(str.lower).values, df2['name'].apply(str.lower).values):
  print (f"{w1}, {w2}, {fuzz.ratio(w1,w2)}")
```

Output:

```
john, ryan, 25
john, kane, 25
john, king, 25
alex, ryan, 25
alex, kane, 50
alex, king, 0
harry, ryan, 44
harry, kane, 22
harry, king, 0
```

Comment: what is w1 and w2 ?How to store this output in a single dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could do:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from itertools import product
import pandas as pd

a = ('John','Alex','harry')
b = ('ryan', 'kane', 'king')

# compute the ratios for each pair
res = ((ai, bi, fuzz.ratio(ai, bi)) for ai, bi in product(a, b))

# create DataFrame filter out the values that are 0
out = pd.DataFrame([e for e in res if e[2] > 0], columns=['name_a', 'name_b', 'fuzz_ratio'])

print(out)
```

**Output**

```
  name_a name_b  fuzz_ratio
0   John   ryan          25
1   John   kane          25
2   John   king          25
3   Alex   kane          25
4  harry   ryan          44
5  harry   kane          22
```

Comment: `fuzz.ratio` and `fuzz.partial_ratio` in FuzzyWuzzy are note case insensitive (they do not even have a case insensitive version). All other algorithms are case insensitive by default.